# How to convert forEach to For Loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, foreach

What is the correct way to convert the forEach to Forloop. Here is my example code.

```
$.get('/files/foods.txt', function (data) {
    var build = "";
    build += "<tr>";
    build += "<th>Pizza</th>";
    build += "<th>Ice cream</th>";
    build += "</tr>";
    build += "<tr>\n";

    var rows = data.split("\n");
    rows.forEach(function getvalues(thisRow) {
        var foodArray = thisRow.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
            build += "<td class=''>" + foodArray[i] + "</td>";
        }
        build += "</tr>\n";
    })

    display.innerHTML = build;
});
```

Comment: what's the problem with `forEach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$.get('/files/foods.txt', function (data) {
    var build = "";
    build += "<tr>";
    build += "<th>Pizza</th>";
    build += "<th>Ice cream</th>";
    build += "</tr>";
    

    var rows = data.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){ 
       build += "<tr>";
       var foodArray = rows[i].split(",");
       for(var j=0;j<foodArray.length;j++){
          build += "<td class=''>" + foodArray[j] + "</td>";
       }
       build += "</tr>";
    }

    display.innerHTML = build;
});
```